# Excel/VBA Why do I get run time error 438 using public variables of workbook and worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn some VBA and in my current project I wanted to learn about using different sub routines so I created a sub to open a CSV file. I wanted to be able to reference the workbook/worksheet in other sub routines so I defined the variables as public. This works fine on it's own and the message box shows the expected values for bankWS and bankWS

```
Public bankWB As Workbook 
Public bankWS As Worksheet 

Sub OpenCSV()
filepath = "C:\" 
csvfile = "file.csv" 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=filepath & csvfile 
Set bankWB = ActiveWorkbook 
Set bankWS = ActiveSheet 
MsgBox "Active WB is " & bankWB.Name & " Active WS is " & bankWS.Name 
End Sub
```

But when I try to reference these variables from a different sub I get run time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or Method.

```
Sub Main()
Call OpenCSV
MsgBox "Active WB is " & bankWB
MsgBox " Active WS is " & bankWS
End Sub
```

I thought the whole point of defining the variable globally was that I would be able to use it outside of the subroutine.

Reading around this error I see that often it occurs when the code is trying to use a particular object (eg worksheet.something) but I think I'm duplicating the msgbox command that worked fine within the sub.  I'm stuck now and can't find out what have I done wrong. I would like to understand, why this error occurs?

Regards

Comment: You haven't stated which property you want to access. Try actually using `.Name` on the end.

Comment: *I think I'm duplicating the msgbox command*  No, you're not :)

Comment: Ah. I was blinkered on the public vs Dim and missed the obvious error.  Thanks for the prompt replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
Call OpenCSV
MsgBox "Active WB is " & bankWB.Name
MsgBox " Active WS is " & bankWS.Name
End Sub
```